# Query to check if date is between two month-day values

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to know if a date (Year-Month-Day) is between a day of the month (Month-Day).

For example, I want to know if 'April 2, 2013' is between 'April 2' and 'April 19'.

I can easily do this of the range has a year value. Howver, without a year, I need ideas how to do this.

Some examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '2013-04-02' BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-19'; -- result is 1
SELECT 1 WHERE '2014-04-02' BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-19'; -- result is 1
SELECT 1 WHERE '2014-03-02' BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-19'; -- result is 1
```

Thanks

Comment: MySql has month and day operators to get the fields you need: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `DATE_FORMAT()`.

**Example**

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
 table
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-19'
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   table
WHERE
   STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '04-01' AND '04-19'
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and this works. Just a question though, does this compare the values as dates? Or how does the comparison works here? As string?

Comment: That doesn't work when you go from December to January (e.g. DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '12-15' AND '01-15')

Answer (score 0):

Following is work with oracle

```
select * from table_name where to_char(date_column, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '08-01' AND '08-14'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The one I'm looking for is for MySQL. Though it seems the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but it does not work if you want to select from December to February as @tony-brix said. You can extend that answer with two `DATE_FORMAT` functions. One goes from December to end of year, other goes from start of year to February.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
 table
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '12-01' AND '12-31'
OR
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '02-01'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).